# Showing prediction output in Keras

Tags: neural-networks, prediction, conv-neural-network, convolution, keras

I am doing a image classification with CNN using Keras. The training process was so far so good. But when it comes to the prediction, I couldn't figure out to extract correct prediction results out of numpy array from predict(x). It is binary classification task but I used softmax layer at the end purposefully. The original labels should look like this:

> [0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]

But I have this from predict:

> [[  1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
>   [  1.00000000e+00 1.13929331e-32]
>   [  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
>   [  1.00000000e+00   1.51848069e-28]
>   [  1.00000000e+00   3.70465143e-38]
>   [  1.00000000e+00   5.44319748e-37]
>   [  1.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
>   [  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]

Apparently, there is a pattern in the output with ones and super small numbers that resembles the real labels although these small numbers should be greater than the ones before them. How can I transform it to look like the original one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing binary classification, each row should give you probability on two classes. In other words, each row should sum up to 1.0.

To get the prediction label, for each row, find the max probability and return the index. Can be done using `numpy.argmax`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Comment: Yes, if I do numpy.argmax(output, axis=1) it gives 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], because apparently in each row of prediction matrix value of 0th index is always greater the second one and always equals to 1. I don't know why but there is a pattern in output matrix which resembles the original answer.

Comment: ok, I see your question, are are asking the difference between 0 and a super small number, like $1.1\times 10^{-32}$. With this detail, it is hard to answer why this happen for me.